# React-Native Emulator and Physical Device Not Working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have Successfully Installed React Native App ,in My Default Android Studio Emulator but It is **not** Working in My Physical Device.

I Changed the Port to 8081 by Executing **$adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081** command.

Then it Started working in My Physical Device but it Stopped Working in Android Studio Default Emulator.

**I Wanted to Change From Physical Device to Emulator**. What Can I Do?
Please Help. Thanks

Comment: You could just unplug your physical device and start the adb server again with **$ adb restart**

Answer (score 0):

Run the adb reverse command again..